# C++ | Access derived class' method through pointer-to-base?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say I have a Base class and a derived class like this:

```
//Base.h
#pragma once
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    ~Base();
private:
    int A;
};

//Foo.h
#pragma once
#include "Base.h"
class Foo : public Base
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void setFoo(int number) { foo = number; };
private:
    int foo;
};
```

Let's say I declare a pointer to base:

```
Base* BasePtr = new Foo();
```

How can I access `setFoo()` using this `Base* Baseptr;` variable?
Can it be done without using virtual methods?
It seems counter-intuitive to have a virtual method in the base only to be able to use `Foo`'s own methods.

The reason I'm asking is I have an assignment that requires an array of pointers to Base, and a way to edit the derived classes' own attributes is required.

Thanks

Comment: You have a problem if you need to know what your derived type is. You should code to an interface that your classes implement and use interface pointers. Interface inheritance is very useful.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
Foo * p = new Foo();
p->setFoo(10);
Base * BasePtr = p;
```

Alternatively:

```
Base * BasePtr = new Foo();
static_cast<Foo *>(BasePtr)->setFoo(10);
```

Comment: In the first way I assume this needs to be done before the declaration of the Pointer-to-base array, alternatively needing to copy the entire object every time i want to access the derived classes' methods.

As for the other methods, if it works, great, but are there downsides to this?

Comment: Isn't it reinterpret_cast even faster than static_cast?

Comment: @EliasFinoli: I'm not sure what kind of copying you're talking about. In real code, I would wrap the logic into a factory function, in which the first form would be entirely natural.

Comment: @KerrekSB Why isn't it correct? You can forcibly cast a pointer to base class, to pointer to derived class, if you know for sure that pointer points to an object of that derived class.

Comment: The derived-to-base conversion isn't in general a simple reinterpretation. The pointer value may need to be adjusted.

Comment: Adjusted in what sense? Adresses are addreses, and all of them have same size, aren't they?

Comment: @Peregring-lk: The address of a base subobject isn't necessarily the same as the address of the containing object, so the pointer conversion may require an offset adjustment.